# How can I call liferay struts action from my own portlet?

Tags: struts, liferay

I define an editPortletURL

```
PortletURL redirectURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
redirectURL.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.POP_UP);
redirectURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/asset_publisher/add_asset_redirect");
editPortletURL.setParameter("redirect", redirectURL.toString());

editPortletURL.setParameter("originalRedirect", redirectURL.toString());
editPortletURLString = editPortletURL.toString();
editPortletURLString = HttpUtil.addParameter(editPortletURLString, "doAsGroupId", assetRenderer.getGroupId());
editPortletURLString = HttpUtil.addParameter(editPortletURLString, "refererPlid", plid);
```

I call the `edit_article.jsp` from my portlet. I will, if I click on "publish" button, I should be forwarded to the jsp page which is pointed to  `/asset_publisher/add_asset_redirect` struts action.
This action is mapped to the `add_asset_jsp`. This page fires `Liferay.fire (closeWindow) event`, which should close the popup window und refresh my portlet.
But If I try to do that - I see my portlet in the popup window...

How can I reference/include Liferay action classes into my own portlet?

Comment: is using `<portlet:actionURL>` and `<portlet:renderURL>` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in liferay 6.1 then you can simply use the action-hook to achive your requirment. Please check below links

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/other-hooks

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-acti-4